# Help interpreting basic Number Theory concept

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm required to prove the following theorem:

> Prove that for any natural number $N$, there exists $N$ consecutive integers none of which is a power of an integer with exponent greater than one

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the meaning of this theorem. I don't know what information it's trying to tell me (I'm really really bad at Number Theory).

Here's my attempt using an example. If we have $N=5$ that means we have five consecutive integers. Which 5 integers? Do I simply pick 5 random integers? If I pick $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $4$ is a power of an integer with an exponent greater than one. That is $2^2=4$. So the obviously I've chosen wrongly the consecutive integers.

Could someone provide me with a detailed numerical example? Thank you for any help

Comment: It looks like you're interpreting the statement correctly. When $N=5,$ we can find the five consecutive integers $17, 18, 19, 20, 21,$ for example, none of which can be written as $x^y$ where $x$ is an integer and $y>1.$ You don't want to poke around randomly, though. It's good for seeing examples but not for proving the statement.

Comment: Your analysis that $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is not a correct choice for $N=5$ is perfectly sound. Did you go any further, and analyze any other consecutive sequences of 5 integers, to see if you could find a correct choice?

Comment: For $ \ N=5 \ \ . $ how about $ \ 51 , 52 , 53 , 54 , 55 \ $ (or any number of other possibilities)?  You just don't want to start too low, so that you avoid squares, cubes, etc. of smaller integers.  As for producing a proof, consider the "sizes of the gaps" between consecutive perfect squares, perfect cubes, and so forth.

Comment: It might be remarked that for the proposition, you only need to prove that such a "run" of consecutive integers _exists_ (although your method may show how to locate such sequences).  Note that the value of $ \ N \ $ could also tell you what the largest exponent is that you need to be concerned with for that sequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arbitrarily long sequences without perfect powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654407/arbitrarily-long-sequences-without-perfect-powers). Also somewhat related is [Prove for each positive integer $n$, there exists $n$ consecutive positive integers none of which is an integral power of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1283188/602049).

Comment: So my goal with finding a suitable $N=5$ consecutive integers is to avoid squares, cubes, ect being in my consecutive set of integers. I do this by considering the "gaps" that exist between cubes, squares, ect. Makes sense.

Comment: @John Omielan Your linked questions offer good proofs for how I can find consecutive integers that contain no perfect squares. Thanks.

Comment: @BobbyB Did you check out the second link provided by John? It claims that for any $n$, there is no number between $n!+2$ and $n! + \frac n2$ which is a perfect power of any integer (not just squares, but any exponent). That answers your question since this is a run of $\frac n2 - 2$ integers without a perfect power, and you can let $n$ be as large as you want to get a run as large as desired.

Answer (score -1):

It means that you have to show that whatever $N$ I give you there is a run that long without a perfect power.  In your example $N=5$.  As you say, $[1,5]$ does not work because of $4$.  Similarly, $[6,10]$ does not work because of $8$ and $9$.  $[37,41]$ works fine because none of the numbers in that range is a perfect power.

If it just asked for a range without a perfect square it would be easy.  We know that $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$ so the range $[k^2+1,k^2+2k]$ has no squares in it.  This is a range of $2k$ numbers, so we can take $k^2+1=\lceil\frac N2\rceil^2+1$ as the first number.  Your problem is harder because one or more of the numbers in the range could be cubes, fifth powers, or so on.

Comment: How is the range $[k^2+1,k^2+2k]$ related to $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$? How did you formulate the ceiling function $k^2+1=\lceil\frac N2\rceil^2+1$? Specifically, why did you choose $k=\lceil\frac N2\rceil$? Sorry if these are basic questions. I always struggle with seeing these "obvious" connections in pure math.

Comment: The range starts just above $k^2$ and ends just below $(k+1)^2$.  That guarantees there are no squares in it.  The length of the range is $2k$.  We need to show a range of length $N$, so we can take $k=\frac N2$.

Comment: @BobbyB k and k+1 are consecutive integers and hence there can not be any integer whose square lies between k^2 and (k+1)^2 since f(x)=x^2 is strictly monotone in (0 infinity).

Comment: @Ross Millikan I'm sorry but I still don't understand. If we need to show a range of length $N$, why do we divide $N$ by $2$? What is that division doing which is so important? If we have $N$ amount of integers, the "range" of $N$ should simply be $N$ itself.

Comment: I divided $N$ by $2$ because given a $k$ I got a run of $2k$ numbers with no squares.  I then need $2k \ge N$ to display a run of $N$ numbers without squares.  For example, with $k=5$ we have $k^2=25, (k+1)^2=36,$ so the run $[26,35]$, which is $10$ numbers has no squares.  If someone challenged me with $N=10$, I could respond with $[26,35]$ based on $k=5$.  If someone challenged me with $N=1000,$ I could respond with $[250001,251000]$ based on $k=500$.

Comment: I don't understand still. What was your direct logic for concluding that you have a run of $2k$ numbers with no squares? I think I need a much more deliberate and basic explanation of how you know that $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$ creates the range $[k^2+1,k^2+2k]$ and why this range demonstrates it has no squares . Assume I don't understand the logic of any step, because I don't.

Comment: It is just like in Lawrence Mano's comment.  We know $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ are successive squares, so all the numbers between them are not squares.

Comment: Okay. So if $k^2$ is a square then $k^2+1$ will not be a square because there are no two consecutive square numbers. But why does $k^2+2k$ represent a non-square number?

Comment: Because the next square after $k^2$ is $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$